# How to display import logs (PostgreSQL / PGAdmin)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using PGAdmin 4 to import some csv into a local database I have on my PC.
I often had some errors during the import but the line was always display in the import log screen. I was then able to open the file and update the specific line.
Since a few days, and I don't know why, the error log is no more display at the import. I am then not able to understand where is the error.
Do you know why the log is no more displayed and how to fiw this?
Thank you,
[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/283703/176905) and its comments can help.

Comment: Perhaps the link is broken :-( Can you please provide an answer that details how to do this? Something as basic as logging should be very explicit and transparent to users, newcomers especially. If you check the PGAdmin 4 FAQ, the Troubleshooting section tells you everything you need to know about the log... EXCEPT how to actually view it!! Highly frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any answers, but have witnessed this same behavior.  I thought it was due to changes in permissions, but it doesn't look like anything there was changed since I saw the error logs.

A time consuming work around for me has been to create a temp version of the table with all fields as text, to import the data into that table, and then to insert the rows of the temp table into the existing table.  I will then see errors for what can't be converted or other problems.  If non-UTF-8 characters got into the file I'm importing that means it won't go into the text file either, and then it is far more guess and test.

Hopefully someone can figure this out!
Claire